# CSS, I dont want an element to float

Tags: html, css

I have been running into problems lately when I am trying to not use the float rule in my css file.

I saw the problem when the other assigned css rules for my div element didn't work without the float.

Can anyone tell me what css rule I should use instead of float when I want it to start a "new line" but not to float?

**Example:**

```
.element1 {width:100%;float:left;margin:20px 0;}
.element2 {width:90%;margin:20px 0;}
```

If I dont assign `element2` with a float, it ignores the margin statement.

Comment: Have you considered `inline-block`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the **clear** property.

```
.element2 {clear:both;} //options are: both, left, right
```

If it is not enough, you may have to add a div to 'clearfix' the break.
Take a look at this technique: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

```
/**
 * For modern browsers
 * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
 *    contenteditable attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
 *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
 *    that are clearfixed.
 * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
 *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
 */
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

You will use it like this:

```
<div class="element1"></div>//floats
<div class="cf"></div>
<div class="element2"></div>//new line, responds to margin, etc perfectly
```

Comment: Then you need a clearfix.. Take a look at: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Answer (score 1):

`clear:both` should do the magic:

**CSS**:

```
.element1 {width:100%;float:left;margin:20px 0;}
.element2 {width:90%;margin:20px 0;}
.clear {clear:both;}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="element1">a</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="element2">b</div>
```